# Journey entry event not updating

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Has anyone run in to issues updating the entry event on a Journey? I'm running in to a situation where the incorrect entry event was originally defined after a journey was activated. After creating a new version, updating the entry event and re-activating - the entry event reverts back to the old incorrect one. Frustrating!

Any thoughts? I'm hoping I don't have to re-create the entire journey from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm rather confused that you were able to update the Event as you can't edit an Event once it's been created. Do you mean that you removed the event in the new version and created a new one?

The behavior you describe should be technically impossible, which is why I think this is related to a configuration issue. I would check the following:

1. Activate the new version — is it active and has it entered a Running state?
2. Open the Events Administration page and check that your new Event appears (that you created in your new version) and that it is in use by the Interaction.
3. Check that the Contact that you are injecting into the Interaction isn't already in the previous version. If it is, and the 'Contact Entry' mode is set to 'Re-entry only after exiting', in [Interaction Settings](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/interaction_settings/) then your Contact will not enter the Interaction again, until they've exited the Interaction from the previous version.

Comment: I found a solution before reading to check on #2. I can confirm the new draft was in a running state, however. I was using a fresh batch of contacts so there is no concern with re-entry. I ended up needing to delete the entry event in the new draft, recreating the entry event, saving, then activate.

Comment: Good to hear that you have resolved your issue. Feel free to vote up and/or mark my answer as accepted, if appropriate.

Comment: Marking your answer as correct. Entry events cannot be changed, even though the Interaction UI makes it seem possible.